# Fitting several zero-inflated negbin models and get pooled results

Tags: r, count, regression, pool

I have a dataset with patient data. Some of the patients have multiple stays in the hospital, but for the observations to be independent (I tried a multi-level model, but it's not possible with this data) I created a dataset, where for each patient that has multiple stays only one stay is selected randomly. Like this, I created 100 datasets with random stays for these patients. My dependent variable is a count variable and a zero-inflated negative binomial model fits best.
I already managed to run the regression model on each of the datasets (the datasets are identified by the variable "sample"), but I don't know how to get a pooled result for all of these 100 regressions. I would like to get the pooled results of the count model and of the zero-inflated model for every predictor.
I'm using:
`library(dplyr); library(tidyverse); library(pscl); library(broom); library(jtools); library(mice)`

The `pool` function is from `mice`.

I created the combined dataset like this:

```
set.seed(12345)

Combined_randcase <- bind_rows(replicate(100, cohort_1 %>% group_by(patient) %>%
                                  slice_sample(n=1, replace = TRUE), simplify=F), .id="sample")

Combined_randcase <- data.frame(as.list(Combined_randcase))
```

I ran the ZINB regression model on each dataset, grouped by "sample", like this (using `broom` package):

```
regr_comb_randcase.zeroinfl = Combined_randcase %>% 
nest_by(sample) %>% 
mutate(model = list(zeroinfl(formula = cm_number ~ after_wm + age + gender_male + ref_mode_police + ref_lg_invol + ref_reas_selfharm + ref_reas_aggrpers + comm_limited + duration_days + diagnosis_personality + diagnosis_psychosis + diagnosis_mania + diagnosis_substance + intoxication | age + gender_male + ref_mode_police + ref_lg_invol + ref_reas_selfharm + ref_reas_aggrpers + comm_limited + duration_days + diagnosis_personality + diagnosis_psychosis + diagnosis_mania + diagnosis_substance + intoxication, data = cohort_1, na.action = na.exclude, dist = "negbin"))) 
%>%
  summarise(tidy(model))
```

That's how I tried to get pooled results:

```
models.zeroinfl <- regr_comb_randcase.zeroinfl$model

pool_results.zeroinfl <- pool(regr_comb_randcase.zeroinfl)
```

When running the second line, I get this error:

```
Error: No tidy method for objects of class character
```

For another logistic regression model, I did this successfully:

```
regr_comb_randcase.log = Combined_randcase %>% 
group_by(sample) %>% 
do(model = glm(cm ~ after_wm + age + gender_male +ref_mode_police + ref_lg_invol + ref_reas_selfharm + ref_reas_aggrpers + comm_limited + duration_days + diagnosis_personality + diagnosis_psychosis + diagnosis_mania + diagnosis_substance + intoxication, data = ., family = binomial()))

models <- regr_comb_randcase.log$model

pool_results <- pool(models)

summary(pool_results)
```

Output of `dput(cohort_1_example)` (a shortened version of my dataset) for reproducibility:

```
structure(list(case = c("20001879", "20009253", "20003748", "20002321", 
"20001662", "1910967", "20008058", "20010686", "20010938", "20009508", 
"20002307", "20010105", "210098181", "21009818", "210100261", 
"21010026", "21000865", "21002199", "1906803", "1907642", "20008274", 
"21000858", "21004557", "1910669", "21004451", "21000202", "21000812", 
"21001006", "21001143", "21001423", "1906820", "21000448", "21002128", 
"21002666", "21003560", "1907070", "20011121", "1907614", "20002748", 
"20010645", "21001363", "1908906", "1910981", "1905926", "21002429", 
"21004264", "20011209", "20010442", "20009977", "1906382", "1909409", 
"1908904", "1910516", "20001534", "20011201", "1907432", "1908332", 
"1906356", "20011026", "20008206", "20000809", "1910664", "1908673", 
"1907610", "1911046", "20008505", "20009385", "21000530", "1909620", 
"1909730", "1910988", "20009899", "1907282", "1906671", "20007870", 
"1910749", "20010782", "20009808", "20003311", "1910722", "1910529", 
"1906638", "1906861", "1906956", "1910743", "20002057", "21000891", 
"20010349", "20008503", "1906093", "1910662", "20008093", "20010683", 
"20008787", "20003631", "20007796", "20008089", "21004141", "20010177", 
"20001316", "1909809", "20001875", "20009552", "20001443", "21000419", 
"20003106", "1909773", "21004600", "20008105", "21002070", "1908245", 
"1909860", "21004209", "21003022", "20003151", "20011037", "21001966", 
"20009902", "1906202", "1910009", "1910777", "20010294", "1910072"
), patient = c("10", "11", "100", "100", "101", "102", "103", 
"105", "106", "107", "108", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "1000", 
"1001", "1002", "1002", "1003", "1003", "1004", "1005", "1005", 
"1006", "1008", "1009", "1009", "1009", "1011", "1012", "1013", 
"1013", "1013", "1014", "1016", "1017", "1018", "1020", "1020", 
"1021", "1022", "1023", "1026", "1026", "1029", "1030", "1033", 
"1035", "1036", "1037", "1037", "1037", "1039", "1041", "1041", 
"1042", "1042", "1043", "1044", "1045", "1046", "1047", "1048", 
"1049", "1050", "1053", "1054", "1056", "1056", "1057", "1058", 
"1060", "1061", "1064", "1064", "1064", "1065", "1066", "1067", 
"1067", "1067", "1067", "1069", "1071", "1072", "1073", "1074", 
"1075", "1075", "1076", "1077", "1078", "1079", "1080", "1081", 
"1082", "1083", "1086", "1087", "1087", "1088", "1089", "1089", 
"1090", "1091", "1091", "1092", "1093", "1094", "1094", "1095", 
"1096", "1098", "1098", "1098", "1099", "1048", "1048", "1021", 
"1018", "1011"), cm = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), cm_number = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), total_cm_duration = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 165.000000003492, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 174.999999994179, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 259.999999998836, 
720, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60.0000000069849, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 815.000000005821, 0, 0, 10865.0000000023, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 420.000000006985, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 200.000000002328, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 239.999999996508, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1084.99999999534, 0, 0, 145.000000001164, 0, 0, 789.999999997672, 
435.000000003492, 0, 0, 60.0000000069849, 0, 0, 0, 0, 775.000000001164, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), after_wm = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), age = c(26, 27, 53, 53, 26, 28, 30, 
57, 39, 50, 49, 27, 28, 28, 27, 27, 89, 18, 22, 22, 21, 21, 58, 
35, 36, 63, 44, 35, 35, 35, 25, 24, 36, 36, 36, 62, 50, 21, 55, 
23, 23, 44, 53, 71, 39, 39, 79, 47, 81, 43, 39, 21, 22, 22, 79, 
22, 22, 33, 35, 86, 27, 42, 20, 30, 25, 22, 26, 62, 54, 46, 46, 
46, 79, 39, 21, 63, 64, 64, 31, 59, 70, 70, 70, 70, 49, 37, 49, 
63, 74, 38, 39, 74, 50, 72, 61, 80, 51, 45, 67, 45, 76, 76, 61, 
30, 31, 35, 48, 49, 45, 30, 76, 76, 20, 18, 20, 20, 21, 51, 24, 
24, 45, 55, 25), gender_male = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ref_mode_police = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ref_lg_invol = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), ref_reas_selfharm = c(1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), ref_reas_aggrpers = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), comm_limited = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), duration_days = c(41, 
1, 2, 42, 3, 46, 3, 8, 1, 1, 21, 64, 25, 2, 25, 2, 22, 26, 7, 
29, 101, 119, 153, 2, 2, 51, 10, 2, 6, 49, 83, 5, 1, 8, 1, 36, 
71, 1, 7, 9, 166, 41, 2, 76, 12, 1, 25, 40, 4, 0, 2, 28, 1, 3, 
49, 29, 54, 95, 119, 29, 28, 26, 43, 1, 15, 121, 22, 28, 73, 
13, 39, 1, 119, 14, 73, 18, 124, 32, 2, 120, 67, 2, 2, 8, 29, 
27, 34, 32, 112, 6, 8, 38, 118, 24, 38, 20, 2, 1, 2, 9, 1, 21, 
42, 57, 49, 1, 1, 1, 35, 2, 45, 23, 64, 29, 2, 6, 56, 0, 5, 3, 
58, 51, 2), diagnosis_personality = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), diagnosis_psychosis = c(1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), diagnosis_mania = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), diagnosis_substance = c(0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), intoxication = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-123L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I could find information on doing this with a linear and a logistic model, but not on a zero-inflated negbin model. Maybe that's why tidy is not working? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you maybe say more about why a mixed/multilevel model isn't possible with these data?  It would also be helpful to list the packages you're using (`library("tidyverse"); library("pscl"); library("mice")` ...)

Comment: Can you also add any relevant `library()` calls like Ben Bolker recommended? It's unclear to me which packages your functions come from, particularly where `pool` is coming from.

Comment: @BenBolker For a multilevel model to work each patient has to have at least two stays (the stay would be level 2, the patient level 1). Unfortunately, this is not the case in my data. Most of the patients have only one stay. I'm using: ```library(dplyr); library(tidyverse); library(pscl); library(broom); library(jtools); library(mice)```. The ```pool``` function is from ```mice```. Although I'm not sure if that's the right way to do it, because I'm not doing a multiple imputation (I just want pooled results similarly to this method).

Comment: Please edit your question to include these libraries, don’t add them in the comments. Good luck!

Comment: I edited the post. Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

Comment: It's not actually true that a multilevel model will only work if each patient has at least two stays, at least not for the multilevel tools I'm aware of (`glmmTMB`, `lme4`, `brms`, `rstanarm`, etc.).  I could post an example if you want, although it isn't technically an answer to the question you asked ...

Comment: @BenBolker yes, I would love an example about the multi-level model! I would definitely prefer such a model over the ones with random stays. I will edit my dataset a bit, so you could fit a logistic (for "cm" as Y, binary) and/or a ZINB (for "cm_number" as Y, count) and/or a linar model (for "total_cm_duration" as Y, continous, only for patients with cm=1). cm stands for coersive measures (in psychiatric care). Or would you do it with another example dataset?

Comment: How big is your full data set?  How many singletons vs non-singleton patients? (The subset you gave has 61 singletons + 62 observations from multiply observed patients ...)

Comment: @BenBolker my original dataset has 1661 observations, with 826 singletons (cases of patients with only one stay) and 835 non-singleton cases (cases of patients with more than one stay). The main predictor variable is after_wm (binary). Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We **can** fit mixed/multilevel models to data with singleton groups; the main constraint is whether there is enough information overall to make estimating the among-group variances feasible.

Among mainstream packages, `lme4` can fit LMMs, logistic GLMMs, and negative binomial mixed models (albeit a bit slowly, and not zero-inflated mixed models without a lot of work: see e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/208829/zip-fit-indices-calculated-from-an-em-algorithm)). `glmmTMB` can handle all of the above. `brms` can do anything `glmmTMB` can do, plus the kitchen sink, but is slower (because Bayesian MCMC) and may need you to get into the weeds of Bayesian/MCMC sampling.

The examples below use your data subset, with considerably simplified models. Your sample data has 86 patients, 61 singletons, 123 total observations. This seems to be nearly enough to fit the simplified models (below); we do run into some of the typical not-quite-enough-data problems with the ZINB fit (zero-inflation term converges to zero probability, NB dispersion parameter converges to a Poisson distribution) and the logistic fit (singular fit, i.e. the among-patient variance converges to zero). These problems are much less likely to occur if your full data set is large ...

The first bit of machinery (besides loading packages) is cosmetic, to avoid too much repetitive code and make it easier to see what common set of predictors is included across all models.

```r
library(lme4)
library(glmmTMB)
## list of all of the fixed effect predictors
fix_vars <- c("after_wm", "age", "gender_male", "ref_mode_police")

## 'resp' is the name of the response variable (character)
ff <- function(resp) {
   reformulate(c(fix_vars, "(1|patient)"), resp = resp)
}
```

```r
## Gaussian/LMM
lme4::lmer(ff("total_cm_duration"), data = dd)

## NB/no zero-inflation
glmmTMB::glmmTMB(ff("cm_number"),
                 family = nbinom2,
                 data = dd)

## NB with (simple) zero-inflation
glmmTMB::glmmTMB(ff("cm_number"),
                 family = nbinom2,
                 ## could use zi = ff(NULL) to include all FE predictors
                 ##  as ZI predictors as well ...
                 zi = ~1,
                 data = dd)

## logistic
lme4::glmer(ff("cm"),
            family = binomial,
            data = dd)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry I'm not a pro in these models and have some questions. Could you explain the first rows? Would I put all my predictors in ```fix_vars``` by creating a subset? What does ```resp``` mean? I get this error: ```Error in reformulate(c(fix_vars, "(1|cohort_1$patient)"), resp = resp) : 
  object 'resp' not found```.

Comment: And are these already multilevel models? What I tried before is this (for negbin model with only the main predictor, without ZI): First with random intercepts: ```v1c1model.nb.ri = glmer.nb(cm_number ~ after_wm + (1|patient), data = cohort_1)``` and then with random slopes too ```v1c1model.nb.rirs = glmer.nb(cm_number ~ after_wm + (after_wm|patient), data = cohort_1)```. I got this error: ```Error: number of observations (=1661) < number of random effects (=2134) for term (after_wm | patient); the random-effects parameters are probably unidentifiable```.

Comment: yes, these are already multilevel.  For the random-slopes model: this error can probably be overridden via  `control = glmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE = "ignore")` (note that all of the issues with identifiability etc. will just get harder with random-slopes models ...)  . `glmmTMB` doesn't do this check.

Comment: Thank you! The models work with the random intercept. When I add random slopes, I get these warnings in the logistic model: ```Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 4.36655 (tol = 0.002, component 1) Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue - Rescale variables?```. In the LMM/gaussian model I can see only the t-values, how can I print p-values? And would you say models with only random intercepts are enough to assume independency in obs.? In the ZINB model with random slopes the main predictor is not sign. anymore (in the one with only random intercepts it is).

Comment: These are headed towards [CrossValidation](https://stats.stackexchange.com) questions. (1) It is generally a good idea to at least consider random slopes, although there is disagreement (Barr et al 2013; Matuschek et al.) about whether they should always be included or whether to do some kind of model selection. (2) probably try `allFit()` to see if the model is reliable despite warnings; (3) see `lmerTest()` for p-values (4) you should be considering which model to use (random int vs random slopes) *before* assessing significance ...